# Why can't I use multiple ids here?

Tags: javascript, image, fade

I'm trying to get a bit of code working. I'm using xfade, latest version. Homebrew Javascript image fader that fades between all img tags in a div, assigned by the Javascript. There's an image fade script I found that uses Javascript to fade between images in a div. However, it can only fade 1 div...I have 3 spots I want to have fading images at, and I can't get the Javascript code to accept the effects to run on another div.

<s>Here's the code I'm using:</s>

http://www.enlinegraphics.com/assets/js/xfade2.js

And the page I'm trying to get the multiple divs with their own set of fading images working is the homepage, aka http://www.enlinegraphics.com

If I'm going about this completely wrong, and the code can't easily run the effects on different DIVs, then I can look for another, but I really need to figure out a good Javascript image fader.

**EDIT**: I'm going to try my hand at JQuery per an answer's suggestion - if you have any help that will help me with that, that would be the focus now, not trying to get xfade working. Thanks.

Comment: Broken link for the xfade javascript...

Comment: I guess the real question is: do you want a fader solution, or do you want to make this specific code (xfade2) work with your project?

Comment: Added some more info for you there below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider implementing and learning jQuery, which has a few plugins to fade things as well as built in functions such as fadeIn(), fadeOut(), etc.

You could use multiple divs fade using a selector like this

```
$('#div1, #div2').fadeOut(1000);
```

Good luck!

### Extra Help

More specifically if at this stage you'd like to get started on fading Div's, check out the jQuery docs at http://docs.jquery.com, more specifically the selectors (for selecting the div) and the effects  (for learning how and which functions to use).

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem doing the banner cycling on http://www.cwu.edu/~campuslife .  While Jquery's fadeout function is nice, it's not going to be adequate for what you're doing. I recommend the Jquery [cycle lite plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/) if you're just fading between images.

To set this up, you'll need to add the jquery script, the cycle plugin, and a third .js file in your document, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="imgrotation.js"></script>
```

Then, in the imgrotation file, add the following lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div1, #div2').cycle()
})
```

That should be all you need to cycle through images in multiple divs.